# Best way to prevent spiders from bogging down a server?

Tags: lamp

I don't know a lot of tech stuff about LAMP servers, but I rent one for several websites and need to know quickly when and if a rogue spider is making too many requests. There are the usual log files, but I don't know how to quickly extract info on IP addresses that are making too many requests. On and off, the server gets so bogged down that queued mail often is delayed by a couple of hours. I have GoogleBot set to its slow crawl rate. Perhaps there are built in resources to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I will post a more theoretical answer, as there are many techniques to "prevent" a complete disaster.

First of all, it is almost impossible to prevent DDoS if the attacker wants it. Changing the IP is very simple and most of the companies and people who do it will also use different routes to get to the same server multiple times.

I think you should start by diving your server into many different machines and layers. Have the first layer or machines (or at least one) to be the main entrance and the other ones to be handling the "already logged in users". This will make so that when you suffer from too many requests, the first layer will be down but the ones below won't be touched.

I don't need to tell that database layer will be on the bottom because its "the thing you'd like to protect the most"

I also suggest using load balancers such as NGINX (http://nginx.org).

Also, don't check the log files. In every request you can get the IP of who is requesting what and so something related to that. Accessing the log might be too late to do anything.

Take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/544523/apache-ddos-prevention.

And also don't forget to check Apache's libraries for preventing DDoS and these kinds of attacks : libapache2-mod-evasive is the one I remember right now :S